# Stock list to only show unique part numbers

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm trying to create a stock list but only showing unique part numbers

The distinct line works and displays only unique part numbers

```
SELECT distinct PartNumber FROM v_StockValuation
```

However when I include this in the following way it displays several lines with the same part number

```
SELECT * FROM v_StockValuation
WHERE partnumber IN 
(
SELECT distinct PartNumber FROM v_StockValuation
 )
 order by PartNumber
```

I've tried adding 
`GROUP BY partnumber HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` but this ends up excluding partnumbers which exist more than once

I'm probably missing something simple. Could someone guide me please?

Thanks

Comment: Before we can answer that you have to decide which values you like to display for the other columns than `PartNumber` which are not unique.

Comment: And which DBMS you are using?

Comment: SQL2008 Express
within the view there are 13 columns but the only column that I need to be distinct is the partnumber

Comment: Tried using group by also as so: (but got the same issue that it lists multiple lines of the same partnumber)
SELECT * FROM v_StockValuation
WHERE partnumber IN 
(
SELECT distinct PartNumber FROM v_StockValuation
 ) 
 GROUP BY partnumber, ItemID, HardwareQuantity, Value,LineValue,MaMID,PartNumber,ItemCategoryID,Code,InvDate,Condition,ValuationDate,WarehouseLocationID,ItemDescription

Comment: So you have the following data (PartNumber,Color,Price): 1,Red,1.95; 1,Green,2.95. What exactly do you want to show for PartNumber=1?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue then. I suppose there can be more than one price for a part number if it's condition is either new or refurbished for example. There is also the itemID field which is unique and relates to the line item but there can be multiple line items which have the same part number. Here is some actual data:

Comment: `code`-ItemID HardwareQuantity Value LineValue MaMID PartNumber ItemCategoryID Code InvDate Condition ValuationDate WarehouseLocationID
-88739 1 15 15 11068 00N6988 8 HDW 19/09/2012 NEW 29/04/2014 71
-88740 1 15 15 11068 00N6988 8 HDW 19/09/2012 NEW 29/04/2014 71
-88741 3 15 45 11068 00N6988 8 HDW 01/09/2013 NEW 29/04/2014 71
-88742 1 10 10 11068 00N6988 8 HDW 19/09/2012 REF 29/04/2014 71
-88743 1 15 15 11068 00N6988 8 HDW 14/04/2013 NEW 29/04/2014 71
-88744 7 15 105 11068 00N6988 8 HDW 19/09/2012 NEW 29/04/2014 71
-88745 1 15 15 11068 00N6988 8 HDW 06/06/2014 NEW 29/04/2014 71

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format the data into a table on here

Comment: Ok, in simplified terms, the fields which will be unique would need to be excluded from the select? (ItemID) and the fields which could have variable data would need to be excluded (Inventory date) 

The object of this is to create an exportable list where the part number is unique as this will reduce the list be several thousand lines

Answer (score -2):

You can do:

```
 SELECT * FROM v_StockValuation group by PartNumber;
```

Comment: This wont compile.  all the other fields that are not partnumber, are not listed in the group by.  No aggregate method is specified.  (I didnt downvote, but only because i dont think you needed any more pile on.)

Comment: It does compile in mysql, still, not sure if this is what the OP is looking for however.  It seems to just drop the other fields.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7c72/1).  I think there is not enough info from OP.